# Missing stdlib symbols when transfering between docker containers

Tags: c++, docker

I'm using docker to do compilation of a C++ project using g++, and I'm hitting a weird case when using multi-stage dockerfiles. I've whittled it down to a small test case

```
FROM alpine:3 AS build
RUN apk add g++
COPY main.cpp main.cpp
RUN g++ main.cpp

FROM alpine:3 AS run
# RUN apk add g++ # Uncommenting this line will make it work for me
COPY --from=build /a.out /a.out
ENTRYPOINT ["/a.out"]
```

and my C++ program:

```cpp
#include<iostream>

int main(void) {
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm noticing when I run a `docker build .` with just this main.cpp and Dockerfile in a folder the container will build properly, but it will then fail to run (via `docker run CONTAINER_HASH`) reporting an error regarding missing symbols, ala:

```
Error relocating /a.out: _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc: symbol not found
...
Error relocating /a.out: _ZSt4cout: symbol not found
```

I've truncated the output, retaining what lines I thought might be helpful given my example program.

Rebuilding the second container and installing `g++` resolves the problem.

This to me is hinting at the fact that:

- `iostream` (and probably other C++ standard library components) are *dynamically* linked. Is this indeed the case? Is there a reasonably reputable location (perhaps the C++ standard website) to find that list? Are those dynamic libraries in a reasonably predictable place in the file system?
- Is there a way to *force* `g++` to *statically* link only the standard libraries I need? My goal is to make my final image as small as possible and *not* installing all of `g++` would be nice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would solve your problem:

```
g++ -static -static-libstdc++ main.cpp
```

By default [g++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) links against shared version:

> When the g++ program is used to link a C++ program, it normally
>   automatically links against libstdc++. If libstdc++ is available as a
>   shared library, and the -static option is not used, then this links
>   against the shared version of libstdc++. That is normally fine.
>   However, it is sometimes useful to freeze the version
>   of libstdc++ used by the program without going all the way to a fully
>   static link. The -static-libstdc++ option directs the g++ driver to
>   link libstdc++ statically, without necessarily linking other libraries
>   statically.